Processing Frames instead of jpg images for Deep Learning Model
I've been trying to implement live translation with a sign language cnn model i made with Keras and OpenCV and im running into an issue with converting the frames to a format the model is able to predict off of.
imgs_dir = r'C:\Users\danie\sign-language-alpha\data\asl_alphabet_test\asl_alphabet_test'
imgs = os.listdir(imgs_dir)

class_mapping = train_images.class_indices

def get_class_label(predictions, class_mapping):
    labels_mapping = {v: k for k, v in class_mapping.items()}
    predicted_labels = [labels_mapping[pred] for pred in predictions]

    return predicted_labels

def predict_image_class(model, img_path, class_mapping):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(imgs_dir, img_path))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = np.expand_dims(cv2.resize(img, (64, 64)), axis = 0)
    predictions = np.argmax(model.predict(img, verbose = 0), axis = 1)
    predicted_labels = get_class_label(predictions, class_mapping)
    return predicted_labels

import cv2
import numpy as np

def process_and_save_video_frame(frame, save_path="processed_frame.jpg"):
    """
    Process a video frame: convert to grayscale, resize with aspect ratio,
    normalize, reshape, and save the processed frame.
    
    Args:
        frame: The original video frame captured from the webcam.
        save_path: The path to save the processed frame image.
    
    Returns:
        frame_final: The processed frame ready for model input.
    """
    def resize_with_aspect_ratio(image, target_size):
        h, w = image.shape[:2]
        target_w, target_h = target_size
        scale = min(target_w / w, target_h / h)
        new_w, new_h = int(w * scale), int(h * scale)
        resized = cv2.resize(image, (new_w, new_h))
        delta_w, delta_h = target_w - new_w, target_h - new_h
        top, bottom = delta_h // 2, delta_h - (delta_h // 2)
        left, right = delta_w // 2, delta_w - (delta_w // 2)
        color = [0, 0, 0]
        new_image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(resized, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=color)
        return new_image

    print(f"Original Frame shape: {frame.shape}")
    
    # Convert to grayscale
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # Resize with aspect ratio
    frame_resized = resize_with_aspect_ratio(frame_gray, (64, 64))
    print(f"Shape after resizing with aspect ratio to 64x64: {frame_resized.shape}")
    
    # Normalize
    frame_normalized = frame_resized.astype('float32') / 255.0
    
    # Add batch and channel dimensions
    frame_final = np.expand_dims(frame_normalized, axis=0)
    frame_final = np.expand_dims(frame_final, axis=-1)
    print(f"Shape after adding batch and channel dimensions: {frame_final.shape}")
    
    # Save the processed frame
    cv2.imwrite(save_path, frame_resized * 255)
    
    return frame_final


for img in imgs:
    predicted_labels = predict_image_class(model, img, class_mapping)
    print(f'Predicted Labels {img} -----> {predicted_labels}')

This is code works and accurately predicts the signs shown from the images in my test data folder. However when Ive tried to implement this same functionality with the frames from an OpenCV Webcam, i was unable to
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model("FINAL.h5")
imgs_dir = r'C:\Users\danie\sign-language-alpha\data\asl_alphabet_test\asl_alphabet_test'
imgs = os.listdir(imgs_dir)

class_mapping = train_images.class_indices
print(f"Class mapping: {class_mapping}")

def get_class_label(predictions, class_mapping):
    labels_mapping = {v: k for k, v in class_mapping.items()}
    predicted_labels = [labels_mapping[pred] for pred in predictions]
    print(predicted_labels)
    return predicted_labels

def predict_image_class_from_path(model, img_path, class_mapping):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    if img is None:
        print(f"Error: Unable to load image at path {img_path}")
        return ["Error"]
    print(f"Original image shape: {img.shape}")
    # Convert to grayscale
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print(f"Shape after converting to grayscale: {img.shape}")
    # Resize the image to 64x64
    img = cv2.resize(img, (64, 64))
    print(f"Shape after resizing to 64x64: {img.shape}")
    # Normalize the image
    img = img.astype('float32') / 255.0
    # Add batch dimension and channel dimension
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=-1)
    print(f"Shape after adding batch and channel dimensions: {img.shape}")
    # Make predictions
    predictions = np.argmax(model.predict(img, verbose=0), axis=1)
    print(f"Predictions: {predictions}")
    # Get the predicted label
    predicted_labels = get_class_label(predictions, class_mapping)
    return predicted_labels

def predict_image_class_from_frame(model, frame, class_mapping):
    # Convert to grayscale
    img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print(f"Shape after converting to grayscale: {img.shape}")
    # Resize the image to 64x64
    img = cv2.resize(img, (64, 64))
    print(f"Shape after resizing to 64x64: {img.shape}")
    # Normalize the image
    img = img.astype('float32') / 255.0
    # Add batch dimension and channel dimension
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=-1)
    print(f"Shape after adding batch and channel dimensions: {img.shape}")
    # Make predictions
    predictions = np.argmax(model.predict(img, verbose=0), axis=1)
    print(f"Predictions: {predictions}")
    # Get the predicted label
    predicted_labels = get_class_label(predictions, class_mapping)
    return predicted_labels
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame, (200, 200))
    predicted_labels = predict_image_class_from_frame(model, frame_resized, class_mapping)
    
    # Display the predicted label on the frame
    cv2.putText(frame_resized, predicted_labels[0], (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    
    # Display the frame
    cv2.imshow('Sign Language Prediction', frame_resized)
    
    # Break the loop on 'q' key press
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

 #{'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3, 'E': 4, 'F': 5, 'G': 6, 'H': 7, 'I': 8, 'J': 9, 'K': 10, 'L': 11, 'M': 12, 'N': 13, 'O': 14, 'P': 15, 'Q': 16, 'R': 17, 'S': 18, 'T': 19, 'U': 20, 'V': 21, 'W': 22, 'X': 23, 'Y': 24, 'Z': 25, 'del': 26, 'nothing': 27, 'space': 28}

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


This keeps returning [27] for every frame aka nothing. Honestly not really sure whats going on here since the model works fine for the images and im converting the frames to the same format as the images.

Step #1 - refactor that code to get rid of the horrible copy-pasta -- the only difference between predict_image_class_from_path and predict_image_class_from_frame seems to be the former has 5 extra lines in the beginning.

@DanMašek I refactored the code  and the issue is still arising, i cant copy and paste the new code here since the text is too long

That's OK, that was just a first step, necessary to retain sanity while debugging it. I suggest you [edit] the question and replace the existing code samples with your refactored code. | Now  you know the processing is the same in both cases, so you ought to look into finding out what the difference is between the two inputs. I suggest you save some of the images you capture from the webcam to disk (in lossless format like PNG). Then try to load them through imread -- the results should be identical to the scenario when reading through VideoCapture. Then, upload some sample input images.
